# new Date() setMonth getMonth bug?

Tags: javascript

I don't understand, why setMonth or getMonth not working correct ?

```
var d = new Date();
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1);
console.log( d );
console.log("Result: "+d.getMonth() + " , why not 11 ?");
```

Output:

```
Date 2017-11-19T22:09:05.418Z 
Result: 10 , why not 11 ?
```

Question is, why d.getMonth() return 10 instead of 11 ?

Comment: Month is zero based index is why. Read the Date docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth

Comment: Please use the search before asking a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return value

An integer number, between 0 and 11, representing the month in the given date according to local time. 0 corresponds to January, 1 to February, and so on.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth